# H2: setting and querying isolation levels - is there a problem on how they are reported by H2?

Tags: transactions, h2

In *H2 2.2.220*

Suppose I set the transaction isolation level from the H2 console:

According to the H2 tutorial, there is a [special H2 console syntax](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#console_syntax) to set or query the transaction isolation level:

- `@transaction_isolation;`: Display (without parameters) the transaction isolation level.
- `@transaction_isolation <levelAsInt>;` Change the transaction isolation level.

The documentation needs a bit of an update here as it does not list level 6, "snapshot", but the level are as follows:

- 1: read_uncommitted
- 2: read_committed
- 4: repeatable_read
- 6: snapshot
- 8: serializable (may only be partially supported, not sure)

It is however unclear what *"the transaction isolation level"* refers to here. Is it the one of the current session? A single global one? The default? But let's go on...

To query *"the transaction isolation level"* then:

```
@transaction_isolation;

Transaction Isolation: 2
1: read_uncommitted
2: read_committed
4: repeatable_read
6: snapshot
8: serializable?: @transaction_isolation
```

So looks like "we are at level `read_committed`"...

The "isolation level" is really an attribute of a "session", as it should be.

The information schema of H2 allows us to query the level of all current sessions:

```
SELECT SESSION_ID, ISOLATION_LEVEL, 
       SESSION_ID = SESSION_ID() AS "IS_MY_SESSION" 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SESSIONS;
```

[image: Result of querying the isolation level #1]

Applying the `@` command apparently changes the isolation levels of all sessions (note that only one, the console session, is active):

```
@transaction_isolation 8;
SELECT SESSION_ID, ISOLATION_LEVEL, 
       SESSION_ID = SESSION_ID() AS "IS_MY_SESSION" 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SESSIONS;
```

[image: Result of querying the isolation level #2]

Makes sense, one might say.

However, a program can set the transaction isolation level too, via the SQL command [`SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS`](http://h2database.com/html/commands.html#set_session_characteristics)

> Changes the transaction isolation level of the current session. The actual support of isolation levels depends on the database engine.

With acceptable values (as defined in the [H2 javadoc](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/engine/IsolationLevel.html)):

- `READ UNCOMMITTED`
- `READ COMMITTED`
- `REPEATABLE READ`
- `SERIALIZABLE`
- `SNAPSHOT` (also works, but is not in the manual)

If one now runs

```
SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL
    READ COMMITTED;
SELECT SESSION_ID, ISOLATION_LEVEL, 
       SESSION_ID = SESSION_ID() AS "IS_MY_SESSION" 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SESSIONS;
```

one would expect *only* the current session to be affected, but this is not what is observed, all the sessions seems to be affected:

[image: Result of querying the isolation level #3]

What to make of this?

Much more troubling:

If I directly query and set the transaction isolation level from a Spring JDBC application using simple code (as added below, this is just for testing, the correct way is to use the [`@Transactional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) annotation and set its `isolation` attribute), then the database reports that indeed the transaction isolation level of the session has been adjusted, i.e. that according to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SESSIONS` the transaction isolation level is for example `REPEATABLE_READ`. But while that is going on, the console *still* reports the transaction isolation level to uniformly be whatever it was set to using with the `@`-command on all existing sessions, much more numerous once the Java program runs.

Is it a display problem? Or do the sessions immediately return to a default set by the `@` command?

I have not yet tried to see whether the isolation levels are truly applied. Soon!

## Java Code for setting and querying the isolation level

A record:

```
public record AboutSession(int sessionId, IsolationLevel isolationLevel) {}
```

Querying the transaction isolation level (code for `IsolationLevel` enum elided):

```
public static AboutSession getAboutSession (@NotNull JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
   return (jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT SESSION_ID, ISOLATION_LEVEL FROM "
              + " INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SESSIONS WHERE SESSION_ID = SESSION_ID()",
              (ResultSet row, int rowNum) ->
                  new AboutSession(
                     row.getInt(1),
                     IsolationLevel.fromString(row.getString(2))))
          ).get(0);
}
```

Setting the transaction isolation level

```
public static void setSessionIsolationLevel(
   @NotNull JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, 
   @NotNull IsolationLevel level) {
      jdbcTemplate.execute("SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS "
         + " TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL " + level.toSql(level));
}
```

The `IsolationLevel` enum, not depending on H2 code:

```
public enum IsolationLevel {

    READ_UNCOMMITTED,
    READ_COMMITTED,
    REPEATABLE_READ,
    SERIALIZABLE,
    SNAPSHOT;

    public static IsolationLevel fromString(@NotNull String x) {
        String xx = x.toUpperCase();
        switch (xx) {
            case "READ UNCOMMITTED" -> {
                return READ_UNCOMMITTED;
            }
            case "READ COMMITTED" -> {
                return READ_COMMITTED;
            }
            case "REPEATABLE READ" -> {
                return REPEATABLE_READ;
            }
            case "SERIALIZABLE" -> {
                return SERIALIZABLE;
            }
            case "SNAPSHOT" -> {
                return SNAPSHOT;
            }
            default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot map string " + x + " to a valid " + IsolationLevel.class.getName());
        }
    }

    public static String toSql (@NotNull IsolationLevel isolationLevel) {
        return switch (isolationLevel) {
            case READ_UNCOMMITTED -> "READ UNCOMMITTED";
            case READ_COMMITTED -> "READ COMMITTED";
            case REPEATABLE_READ -> "REPEATABLE READ";
            case SERIALIZABLE -> "SERIALIZABLE";
            case SNAPSHOT -> "SNAPSHOT";
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a bug in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

Isolation level of the current session is returned in all rows instead of actual isolation levels of sessions described in these rows.

I filled a new issue for this bug:
https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3868

*Edited:* This bug was fixed in H2 2.2.222.

Comment: Well, it took me some time to get back to this question. In the meantime, my understanding of H2 and transactions has improved markely :-) Thank you in any case.